# How is this radical transformed?

Tags: calculus, physics

[Wave equation derivation](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m256/wave.pdf)

In the link shown above, there is a derivation of the wave equation. At line (1), the author says that he divides equation by $\Delta x$ and takes the limit as this quantity is approaching 0. How does the equation go from p(x)$\sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta u^2}$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$ to p(x)$\sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2}$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$ on the left side? I don't understand that at all.

Comment: Divide by $\Delta x^2$ and take the limit as x approaches zero.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I don't see how that would work. How can you just divide the radical quantity by $\Delta x^2$ out of nowhere?

Comment: If this radical is on the left hand side, then you should do the same to the right hand side and you would be OK. Checking the text you placed a link for, it does not show that it performed the division or the limit on the right hand side, which is a bit strange.

Comment: You may get more responses if you ask this in a Physics forum, where someone could recommend a better text for the derivation of the equation.